# How to delegate control of an html page two 2 independent jquerymobile pages

Tags: html, iframe, jquery-mobile

I am experimenting on jquery mobile and wish to try the given setup:

- 2 jquery mobile pages being fully embedded into a div each.
- Each div of a fixed size area side by side, on the current html page.
- I wish to have messages (or jquery callbacks) between the two jquerymobile pages.

Yet, the only configuration that I was able to succeed with, is
by embedding my jquery mobile pages into 2 separate iframes.  My fear, 
justified or not, is that by using iframes, I uses heavy resources on the
browser side, as opposed to use simple divs.  Furhermore, I am
imposing on my development another layer of communications between
the two (iframes) pages, which is not sexy.

I do not seem to be able to control the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

for multiple embedded divs in a single page.  In fact, poping up a dialog
box from one div, takes control of the overall html page.

Questions:

1. Am I trying to do something not meant to be done ?
2. Does an iframe is consuming that much resources as I suspect ?

Thanks for your help and comments.

Comment: Sorry, where can I accept an answer (to promote the rate I guess) ?

Comment: To the left of every answer to one of your question you should see an outline of a check-mark, if that answer resolves your issue then you should mark it as the accepted answer. This way people that may have the same issue as you and find your question can see what worked. Take a look at the FAQ for more info http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Thanks, I will be more careful.